# How to setup ofxUnitTests or any other unit testing framework in openframeworks?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, openframeworks

I try to setup unit testing for my openframeworks project. I decided to use the addon ofxUnitTests.
I create a new blank project to test it.

Their is my main.cpp code:

```
#include "ofMain.h"
#include "ofAppNoWindow.h"
#include "ofxUnitTests.h"

class ofApp: public ofxUnitTestsApp{
public:
    void testEqual(){
        ofLogNotice() << "---------------------------------------";
        ofLogNotice() << "testEqual";

        ofxTestEq(1, 1, "Result should equal the expected value");
    }

    void run(){
        testEqual();
    }
};

//========================================================================
int main( ){
    ofInit();
    auto window = make_shared<ofAppNoWindow>();
    auto app = make_shared<ofApp>();
    // this kicks off the running of my app
    // can be OF_WINDOW or OF_FULLSCREEN
    // pass in width and height too:
    ofRunApp(window, app);
    return ofRunMainLoop();
}
```

It compile but when i execute it nothing append.The code execute like a normal project but without  window. No log in console to confirm the test execution.